# Select SQL With 2 table

Tags: sql

I have 2 table

```
User
Colum : User_id,user_name,email

User_Authenticate 
Colum : user_id,user_key,hash
```

Can i ask for query to get data form 2 table by 1 query with the value is email or user name?

Thanks all

Comment: Yes, google for SQL JOIN. For example: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: @DennisHunink please don't give w3schools links, http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM User u
JOIN User_Authenticate ua
    on u.User_id = ua.user_id 
WHERE u.user_name = 'yourusername'
    OR u.email = 'yourname@email.com'
```

Comment: Modify `on` to `on u.User_id = ua.user_id`.

Comment: @AhmedJolani thanks I obviously wasn't paying attention when I wrote it :)

Comment: No problem :) still one error `u.user_id` should be `u.User_id` :P

Comment: Thanks your verymuch. I Can get data form 2 table now. I try to query with my Query : SELECT * FROM User_Authenticate WHERE 
user_id=(SELECT user_id FROM User_Authenticate  WHERE email ="email") and only get one, haha. Thanks you

Comment: @Mif.ComicVN happy to help, if this works then mark it as the accepted answer via the checkmark on the left.

Answer (score 1):

The result will output user's info as this:

```
email  user_name  user_key  hash
-----  ---------  --------  ----
x@x.x   xxxx       xxxx     xxxx
```

Of course the result will be related to the other table User_Authenticate.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT email, user_name, user_key, hash FROM User JOIN User_Authenticate ON User.User_id = User_Authenticate.user_id AND email='EMAIL-ENTERED' AND user_name='USERNAME-ENTERED'
```

Enjoy! And next time please search Google before you ask a question no need for redundancy!

Comment: Separating tables by commas is still a join and is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM user JOIN User_authenticate ON User.user_id=user_authenticate.user_id WHERE user.email = $something
```

Just a very scratch try, should give you some hints..